# Shell script to grep in a range of files

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I'm setting up a script which takes some user data with the `read` command. Using this data I need to search the file range and then do some filtering.
Here's how it is,

```
Enter fromtime

read fromtime

Enter totime

read totime

Enter the ID

read id
```

Initially I SSH into a server and then there I have a directory, Records with path `cd home/report/records` here, I have:

- `REC_201901020345.gz` (yyyymmddhhmm)
- `REC_201901120405.gz`
- `REC_201903142543.gz`

and so on.

These files have data along with the `$id`.

When the user inputs `$fromtime` and `$totime` it will be of format yyyymmddhh . Here, I need to go to that range of files and then `grep` for the `$id` and display. For example:

If `$fromtime` is `2019010103` and `$totime` is `2019031425`. I need to go to only those specific range of files that is `REC_201901020345.gz`, `REC_201901120405.gz`, `REC_201903142543.gz` and perform the `grep` to find the `id` entered by the user.

I have tried this using an `if` condition but it doesn't seem to work. I am new to writing scripts like these. There might be mistakes when I have described everything here. Sorry for the same.

```
source config.sh

Enter fromtime

read fromtime

Enter totime

read totime

Enter the ID

read id

ssh $user@$ip


cd /home/report/records

# <-- need to know what to add here as described here, to navigate to the
# <-- specific range $fromtime-$totime. Then the command to find id will be 

zfgrep $id *.gz
```

The result should be only the the data with the `id`'s in the specified range of `.gz` files.

Comment: How many files are there in your directory? hundrets, some view thousands or even more? Can you please post your code, you have so far?

Comment: The file will be `REC_yyyymmddhhmm.gz` there is no change other than a the date right?

Comment: @Edvin it will be in the format and input will be yyyymmddhh only .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below command.

```
echo -e "$(ls -1 REC_????????????.gz 2>/dev/null)\nREC_${fromtime}##\nREC_${totime}##" | sort | sed -n "/##/,/##/p" | sed '1d;$d' | xargs zfgrep -a "$id"
```

Explanation:
'fromdate' and 'todate' along with a `##` (say marker) is appended to the output of `ls`.
Sorted the input, resulting in desired file names enclosed with marker.
Both `sed`, prints only lines between marker.
Last one is the command, supposed to be executed for each file name.

You can omit pipes and all next commands, starting from end, and see how output is building.

Comment: Ah that's a creative solution. I like it. Not really easy to understand without a good amout of comments, but that's how things are often in bash programming.

Comment: If it will be used inside a `ssh $user@$ip` `$` that not belong to variable from the script but belong to the execution on the remote host side like `$(ls...)` or in sed `$d` needs to be escaped `\$`.

Comment: @user0 i need the range of files between fromdate and todate, this does not give me the range of files but just gives files with fromdate and todate

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of files within the given range (fromtime, totime), the following shell script may be used:

```
declare -i ta
for file in REC*.gz
do 
    ta=$(echo "${file}" | grep -oP 'REC_\K(.*)(?=[[:digit:]]{2}.gz)')
    if [ "${ta}" ] ; then  
       if [ ${ta} -le ${totime} -a ${ta} -ge ${fromtime} ] ; then 
          echo -e "${file}"
       fi
    fi  
done
```

Comment: im getting a bash script error as too many argyments existing

Comment: It seems that there are files that do not have `REC` prefix in the same directory. That's why error occurred. Code was updated to handle the issue.